# What does power of logarithm (log) mean?

Tags: logarithms

Here an example of what i am asking

> $$\log_2^08=\,?$$
>
> $$\log_2^28=\,?$$
>
> $$\log_2^{-1}8=\frac1{\log_28}=\,?$$

First question is $\log^0 8$ at base $2$

Second question is $\log^2 8$ at base $2$

Also $\log^{-1} 8$ at base $2$ is equal to $1/\log8$ at base $2$?

edit i am asking in analysis of algorithms context. so it is about time complexity

Answer (score 3):

$$\log_2^08=(\log_28)^0=3^0=\,?$$$$\log_2^28=(\log_28)^2=3^2=\,?$$$$\log_2^{-1}8=(\log_28)^{-1}=3^{-1}=\,?$$

Comment: could you edit your answer for another context as well? where it means log(log n))

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Some times $\log_2^38$ means $(\log_2 8)^3$, some times it means $\log_2(\log_2(\log_2 8))$. Without more context it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Hmm... I've always seen that $\log_a^px=(\log_ax)^p$. Can you show me where it can mean the other?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire When analysing the time complexity of algorithms, it's conventional to write $\log^2n$ when you mean $\log(\log n)$.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know (+1).

Comment: $\log^{-1}$ can also be the functional inverse of $\log$.

Comment: @Arthur: I disagree. In algorithm complexity, $\log^2n$ is the squared logarithm and the twice iterated logarithm is denoted $\log\log n$.

Comment: I am asking log(log n)) could you edit your answer in that context?

Comment: I also never saw the alternative interpretation, good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Simply
$$\log_a^bx=(\log_ax)^b.$$

Answer (score 0):

The standard interpretation is

$$\log_a^n b=(\log_a b)^n$$